# Find most rented action film in the US - SQL query

Tags: sql, database

I have been trying to find the amount of action films rented in the US from a dvd rental database. However, my code returns N/A. Tips?

```
select f.title, count(r.rental_id)
    from country c, city cc, address a, customer ccc, rental r, inventory i, film f, film_category fc, category cccc
    where c.country_id = cc.country_id
    and cc.city_id = a.city_id
    and a.address_id = ccc.address_id
    and ccc.customer_id = r.customer_id
    and r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
    and i.film_id = f.film_id
    and f.film_id = fc.film_id
    and fc.category_id = cccc.category_id
    and cccc.name = 'Action' 
    and c.country = 'United States'
```

Comment: Tag the RDBMS you are using - I don't know any that would return N/A for this query. Also use more modern joins using an ON clause instead of that endless WHERE

Comment: Suggestion: rewrite you query using standard `JOIN  ... ON ...` syntax. It will be easier to analyze.

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, instead of that old syntax from the 80s.

Comment: You also need an appropriate `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: In addition, you could tell more about where exactly you are seeing the _"N/A"_ result, in one of the two columns you Selected? Can you provide a few `Create Table` and `Insert Into` lines that would reproduce the effect?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do, is format your joins using `JOIN` syntax instead of creating a long, messy WHERE statement that can be harder to debug (especially when asking on Stack Overflow!)

Another thing that is helpful when asking SQL questions, is to mention which type of database you are using. Every RDBMS has it's own flavor and nuance, so sometimes it helps to know exactly which one you're working with.

Lastly, it can help if you give the exact error that you're getting. I don't think N/A is an error, so I'm not sure if you're getting an error or if you're just getting no results which indicates a problem with your joins.

Either way, I noticed your query is missing a `GROUP BY` clause which is required when you're doing a `COUNT`, or other aggregation.

Try this query and let us know if you get the results you expect. And if not, please post the details to make helping you easier. :)

```
SELECT f.title,
       Count(r.rental_id) AS RENTAL_COUNT
FROM   rental r
       INNER JOIN customer ccc
               ON r.customer_id = ccc.customer_id
       INNER JOIN address a
               ON a.address_id = ccc.address_id
       INNER JOIN city cc
               ON cc.city_id = a.city_id
       INNER JOIN country c
               ON c.country_id = cc.country_id
       INNER JOIN inventory i
               ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
       INNER JOIN film f
               ON i.film_id = f.film_id
       INNER JOIN film_category fc
               ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
       INNER JOIN category cccc
               ON fc.category_id = cccc.category_id
WHERE  cccc.NAME = 'Action'
       AND c.country = 'United States'
GROUP  BY f.title
ORDER  BY Count(r.rental_id) DESC;
```